# Modificar valores dependiendo de la fecha

Tags: mysql

Estaba trabajando en una base de datos propia en mySQL(soy novato) y quería saber si era posible incrementar el valor de un campo (por ejemplo "Dinero") bajo un procedimiento almacenado pasado un determinado tiempo.
Ejm:
Contar con una cantidad inicial de 0 dolares a las 20:00 hrs, y cada que pasen 24 horas desde el último registro se incremente el valor en 4 dólares.

Comment: Buscar por "mysql task scheduler"

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas cómo funciona la comunidad y de paso vas ganando reputación.